# Replace substring within several urls

Tags: jquery, regex

My html:

```
<select onchange="getval(this);">
  <option value="user1">user1</option>
  <option value="user2">user2</option>
  <option value="user3">user3</option>
</select> 


<a class="local" href="http://subDomain.www.mysite.com">Site</a>
<a class="local" href="http://subDomain.www.mysite.com/admin">Admin</a>
<a class="local" href="javascript:open_wins('http://subDomain.mysite.com', 'http://subDomain.mysite.com/admin');">Both</a>
```

My script:

```
<script>
  function getval(sel) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var x = (sel.value);
      var regex = new RegExp(Globally replace the subdomain of urls on select change);

      $('.local').attr('href', function(i, val) {
        return val.replace(regex, x);
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

I want to be able to dynamically replace whatever the current subDomain string is, e.g., user1 with the option value I select from my form.

This script may not be elegant, but it works to replace a static string in the url. What I'm trying to do is replace everything between "http://" and ".", but try as I may, I cannot figure out the proper regex to do so.

Comment: You shouldn't have a `$(document).ready` within your `getval` function.  It should be wrapping it if anything.

Comment: You mean `http://subDomain.mysite.com` should become `http://user1.mysite.com`?

Comment: mvChr: you are correct, and I can fix that.

Comment: hjpotter: Yes. And when I select user2 from my select box, user1 needs to become user2, etc.

Comment: Explosion Pills: That _almost_ works, but it leaves off the last ".", e.g., subDomain.www.mysite.com becomes user1www.mysite.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getval(sel) {
    var x = (sel.value);
    var regex = new RegExp(/http:\/\/\w+\./g);
    $('.local').attr('href', function (i, val) {
        return val.replace(regex, "http://" + x + '.');
    });
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3jbfD/

Comment: Thanks to everybody for smart, speedy responses! hjpotter92's solution works perfectly.